# We are using AWS SNS service for sending sms for different countries from last year suddenly for US numbers sender id is changing

Tags: amazon-sns

We are using AWS SNS service for sending sms for different countries from last year suddenly for US numbers sender id is changing
on US numbers each sms receives from every different number.
Do we have any solution for that ?

Comment: Are you providing a Sender ID when sending the messages? See: [Sending an SMS message - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html)

Comment: No we did not provided any sender id till now the msg is sent by some random numbers but suddenly the sms are sent by different numbers

Comment: The above link suggests you can set the Sender ID when sending the message. Does this help?